# Problem with basepath or apppath in CodeIgniter with SSL - looking in wrong place?

Tags: codeigniter, ssl, path

I have an app in the main directory of my site at www.mysite.com and another development version of the same site in a subdomain http://dev.mysite.com.  Both the public_html and dev_html directories are on the same level - ie. they are both contained within the same directory.  When I access the dev site via http:// everything is fine - it displays as it should.  However, once the user authenticates and the site switched to https:// the dev application starts looking at the controllers and views in the public_html directory. I have no idea why - all links, forms and redirects are relative so they shouldn't jump to the controllers and views in the public_html folder.  Also, the URL continues to show https://dev.mysite.com/

Does anyone have any idea where I should start to look?  The config.php file has all the correct values.  Also, here is the auth_controller which extends the base controller.

```
class Auth_Controller extends My_Controller {

Public $auth;
Private $CI;
Public $auth_levels = Array();

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->data['user_realname'] = $this->db_session->userdata('user_realname');
        $this->auth = $this->db_session->userdata('userAuthLevel');

        $this->CI =& get_instance();
        $this->auth_levels = $this->CI->config->item('auth_levels');

            if ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != 443)
            {
            redirect(uri_string(), 'location', TRUE);
            }
    }
}
```

Any help on how to debug this would be appreciated.

CodeIgniter version is 1.71.

Comment: It has internationalisation as well so there is a custom url helper - but it just references config variables - no absolute urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked your virtual host configuration in the web server config? This can seems obvious, but in apache's virtualserver you need to specify the port, and ssl is falling into the default-ssl config.

Comment: Hi Carlos, I think this was the cause. I'm setting up a separate virtual host on a different IP. I'll report back after I see if it worked.  Thanks!

Comment: Yep - that was the problem.  I moved the development subdomain to its own virtual host and now everything is working fine.  Thanks very much for pointing me in the right direction!